How can I use NodaTime with redis?
I am using the HybridCahce implementation from .net 9, with a DragonFly instance as the distributed cache, and works as expected with:
builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options => options.Configuration = redisConnectionString);
..
builder.Services.AddHybridCache(options => options.ReportTagMetrics = true);

However, when I try to cache something that has NodaTime's Instant in it that property is empty in the store.

In general, to use NodaTime, it needs to be added to the serializer.
Works with MassTransit and RabbitMQ when configured like this:
x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
{
    ...
    cfg.ConfigureJsonSerializerOptions(j => j.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb));
    ...
});

But how can I achieve the same with the cache?
I have implemented IHybridCacheSerializer<Instant> and registered with the DI container, but it is never called. .AddSerializer is just a wrapper around .AddSingleton, hence does the same: nothing.
Based on the stock implementation of AddHybridCache, I have reimplemented IHybridCacheSerializerFactory to try to resolve specific serializers - but makes no difference, that service is also never resolved.
The only workaround I found is adding the NodaTime serializers to the default converter list using reflection. But that's a huge hack: How to globally set default options for System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?
[Update]
Based on Mark Gravel's clarification I reimplemented the default IHybridCacheSerializerFactory to use its own JsonSerializerOptions instance. That's an absolutely acceptable solution.

HybridCache's AddSerializer method only applies to the main object that you're serializing - effectively, the T in GetOrCreateAsync; it looks like the T in your case is some other DTO (I'll go out on a limb and guess class ProxyUser, although it doesn't matter), so what matters is: how ProxyUser (or whatever) is configured.
If, however, the problem is that you'd like a way to set default JsonSerializer options for HybridCache: that's great, please log that here and I'll take a look.

Ah, ok, I understand. The serializer is not a converter, it's all or nothing. I have reimplemented the DefaultJsonSerializerFactory with my own JsonSerializerOptions, added with .AddSerializerFactory<> and it works.
